# Compiler Error: "‘e’ was not declared in this scope" in C code

Tags: c, compiler-errors, arduino, declaration

When I compile my Arduino sketch(language C), I get the error:

```
sketch_oct30b:2: error: ‘e’ was not declared in this scope
sketch_oct30b:2: error: ‘z’ was not declared in this scope
```

This is the piece of code, `char z` is in the first line of the whole code.

```
char z[4] = "z_0";
int e = 0;

char delta(e, z) {}
```

From what I found out this error means that the programmer forgot some declaration, but I don't really see where I forgot to declare `e` or `z`.
Can someone tell me where I forgot to declare?

Comment: If those are global variables, you can just get rid of the `e` and `z` in the function parameters.

Comment: @ooga Why? Doesn't the function need to know with what parameters it is supposed to work?

Comment: If the variables are "global" then they are visible in all functions and not only *don't* need to be declared as function parameters, but in fact *can't* be (with the same name) since then the local parameter variables would "shadow" the global variables and they won't be accessible. Still, global variables are in general a bad idea so you might want to look at the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that in this function definition

```
char delta(e, z) {}
```

names e and z are not declared,

Either you have to specify a parameter list as for example

```
char delta( int e, char z[]) {}
```

or anidentifier list

```
char delta(e, z) int e; char * z; {}
```

Comment: So, I have to declare the variables again, okay. But that leaves me wondering why I get the error for line 2, and not 4 ?

Comment: @Merlin You should show the actual code. The code you showed does not correspond to the errpr messages.

Comment: I already fixed the error, so I don't have the old code anymore, but the whole code began with char z[4] = "z_0".(It was only that one function). That's why I was so confused about the error being in line 2.

Comment: @Merlin O'k. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If `char delta(e, z) {}` should be a function definition, you have to remember the proper syntax to do so.

```
char delta(int e, char *z) 
{
    char result;

    /* do whatever here... */

    return result; 
}

char z[4] = "z_0";
int e = 0;

char result = delta(e, z);
```